# Brain boiling from MySQL - How to do a complicated select from multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, database

I have two tables: Users and Groups

In my table "Users", there is a column called "ID" for all the user ids.

In my table "Groups" there is a column called "Participants", fields in this column are filled with all the user ids like this "PID_134,PID_489,PID_4784," - And there is a column "ID" that identifies a specific group.

Now what i want to do, i want to create a menu that shows all the users that are not yet in this particular group.

So i need to get all the user ids, that are not yet in the Participants column of a group with a particular ID.

It would be cool if there was a single mysql query for that - But any PHP + MySQL solutions are okay, too.

How does that work? Any guesses?

**UPDATE:**
i know, that's not code, but is there a way I could do something like this that would return me a list of all the users?

```
SELECT * 
FROM users, groups 
WHERE groups.participants NOT LIKE '%PID_'users.id'%' AND groups.id = 1;
```

Comment: Select * from users where userid not in (select participants from groups where groupie=x)

Comment: Any reason that participant IDs are strings instead of numbers?

Comment: This is a tricky one - your `groups` table is non-normalised (one column to hold multiple values). Are you able to break this out to two tables?

Comment: You should redesign your tables to make data normalized. If there can be only one group per user, introduce field `GroupId` in the `Users` table. Otherwise, you need a third "many-to-many" table with fields `UserId` and `GroupId`.

Comment: Is Participants column a multivalued field?  That is, if I got a single row for a group, would the value of that field be something like 'PID_134,PID_489,PID_4784'?  A list of comma-separated values?

Comment: yes mdoyle, you're right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this. You just get rid of "PID_" part of ID.

```
SELECT * FROM [users] WHERE [id] NOT IN 
(SELECT replace(id,'PID_','') FROM groups WHERE group_name='group1')
```

Group1 would be your variable - group id/name of menu that you've opened.

Answer (score 0):

You can select from multiple tables as shown below:

```
SELECT * from users, groups WHERE users.id != groups.participants AND groups.id = 1;
```

This will list all users who are not in group id 1; A more elegant solution can be found by using joins, but this is simple and will do the trick.

Comment: i tried that, doesn't work... already tried a LIKE, too but let's imagine there is a user with the id 11, who is not in the group and one with the id 111, who is already in the group - this select would say that the user 11 was already in this group? remember, my participants field in this row would be "PID_1,PID11," etc...

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like that should help:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.id NOT IN (SELECT groups.participants FROM groups)
```

But this works only if your DB is normalized. So for your case I see only PHP + MySQL solution. Not very elegant, but it does the job.

```
<?php
$participants_array = mysql_query("SELECT participants FROM groups");
$ids = array();
while ($participant = mysql_fetch_assoc($participants_array))
{
  $id = explode(',', $participant['participant']);
  foreach ($id as $instance)
  {
    if (!in_array($instance, $ids)) $ids[] = $instance;
  }
}
$participants = implode(',', $ids);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id NOT IN ( $participants )");
```

But I highly recommend normalizing the database.

Comment: still doesn't take the "PID_" into account

Comment: Added PHP code - this one should work. If your ids are integer - you can do str_replace to remove "PID_". But again, it's better for you to normalize your database.